# Symfony user locale subscriber not changing my locale

Tags: php, symfony

am trying to change the locale base on user locale attribute, so i build this listener:

```js
<?php

namespace FrontOfficeBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;
use Plein\Core\Entity\User;

class UserLocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if (null !== $user->getLocale()) {
            $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => [['onInteractiveLogin', 7]],
        ];
    }
}
```

I also have the locale listner:

```js
<?php

namespace FrontOfficeBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct(string $defaultLocale = 'nl')
    {

        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered after the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
        ];
    }
}
```

As you can see the priority of user subscriber is lower than locale listener, and after the firewall priority. Those listner are configured in parameters.yaml:

```js
imports:
  - { resource: ./parameters.php }

parameters:
  locale: nl
  locales: nl|en

  FrontOfficeBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener:
    tags: [{ name: kernel.event_subscriber }]

  FrontOfficeBundle\EventListener\UserLocaleSubscriber:
    tags: [ { name: kernel.event_subscriber } ]
```

Also my framework.yaml:

```js
framework:
  translator:
    fallbacks: ["%locale%"]
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
  secret: "%secret%"
    strict_requirements: ~
  form:            ~
  csrf_protection: ~
  validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
  default_locale: "%locale%"
  trusted_hosts:   ~
```

I have "nl" as default and am trying to login with user who has "en" as locale. but i dont know why the locale is always switched to default "nl".

Before login:

[image]

After login:

[image]

While debugging am trying to follow the process, first app will launch the locale listener and setting the default, then he went to the UserSubscriber and setting "en" in the session, finally back to locale listener and then he will find in the attribute ('nl') cause it was seted at the first step. But why my priorities are ignored or womething? and why i cant set the user locale? please any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    $locale = substr($request->getPreferredLanguage(), 0, 2);
    // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
    if ($locale) {
        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }
}
```